# how to delete records from ms access in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Ive seen tutorials on the net on how to do it, but the tutorial is not applicable on the program that I wish to do. The tutorial tells you to add  4 navigation buttons so that you can navigate the database(first, last, back, and forward). Then an update and delete button.
But if this is what I will do, it would take 10 years to navigate the database and update a record.
Now, what I want to do is just for the user to input a unique ID and click search button(which I have already done). Then the update would be easier. How can I update or delete a record using this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines:-

```
Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=MyDatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;")
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim _ID as Integer=1 

cmd.Connection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM blah WHERE primarykey=" & _ID
Using cnn
   cnn.open()
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  Imports System.Data.OleDb      
  Dim conn2 As OleDbConnection
        Dim DeleteData As OleDbCommand
conn2 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="table location here";Persist Security Info=False;")
    sql1 = "DELETE * FROM [Audit Log]" ' query for deleting data
        conn2.Open() ' openning second connection for clearing purpose
        DeleteData = New OleDbCommand(sql1, conn2) 'second connection to remove information from the old table
        DeleteData.ExecuteNonQuery()
```